# Toggle values from 1 to 0 sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to set default_option value of all other rows to 0 and one specific row to 1.

```
public int updateDefaultPayOptions(String id) {
        String whereValues[] = new String[]{id};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(Constants.DEFAULT_OPTION, 1);     
        return db.update(Constants.MY_TABLE, newValues, Constants.OPTION_ID + "=?", whereValues);
    }
```

Only row with Option_ID as id should have DEFAULT_OPTION as 1 and rest of the rows should have DEFAULT_OPTION set as 0.

How do I achieve it efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set all rows of table to 0:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
 newValues.put(Constants.DEFAULT_OPTION, 0);     
 return db.update(Constants.MY_TABLE, newValues, null, null);
```

and then use your function to change your one row with some ID to 1.